# How do I use the same int in different functions?

Tags: javascript, needle.js

I want to use the `int balance` and `cPercent` and so on in both of my functions. How would I do this?

[link to pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YRaWb2uZ). And the code:

```
int main()
{
    int balance = 100;
    int cPercent;
    float bet;
    float thirty = 1.3;
    int outcome;
    std::cout << "Welcome!\n";
    std::cout << "\nYour balance is currently: " << balance << "$\n";
    std::cout << "Would you like to have 50% or 30% or 70% chance percent of winning?\n";
    std::cout << "Type 1 for 30%, 2 for 50% and 3 for 70%";
    std::cin >> cPercent;

    while(1){}
}

void gamble()
{
    int gPercent = (rand() % 10);
    if (cPercent = 1) {
        if (gPercent < 3) {
            outcome = floor(bet * thirty);
        }
        else if (cPercent = 2) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things: make global variables or pass the variables as parameters.

To make global variables then declare the two variables outside of the two functions like so

```
int balance;
int cPercent;
```

before the definitions of both functions. Alternativel you can pass the integers as a parameters to the function that you are calling in order for it to be "in scope". If you want to use `cPercent` and `balance` in the `gamble` function, then you need to change it's method signature to.

```
void gamble(int balance, int cPercent)
{
    //definition, etc...
}
```

and then when you to to call the function from the `main` function you need to pass them in like so:

```
gamble(balance, cPercent)
```

This causes a copy of the integers to be in scope in the `gamble` function.

Comment: It's best to mark answers with a checkmark if they solved your issue. That way if someone else has this issue while searching they can see this answer was resolved. Thanks